# MongoDB, pymongo: algorithm to speed up identification of consecutive documents with matching values

Tags: python, algorithm, mongodb, match, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB and pymongo and looking for some guidance in terms of algorithms and performance for a specific task described below. I have posted a link to an image of the data sample and also my sample python code below.

I have a single collection that grows about 5 to 10 Million documents every month. It receives all this info from other systems, which I have no access to modify in any way (they are in different companies). Each document represent sort of a financial transaction. I need to group documents that are part of a same "transaction group".

Each document has hundreds of keys. Almost all keys vary between documents (which is why they moved from MySQL to MongoDB - no easy way to align schema). However, I found out that three keys are guaranteed to always be in all of them. I'll call these keys key1, key2 and key3 in this example. These keys are my only option to identify the transactions that are part of the same transaction group.

The basic rule is: 
- If consecutive documents have the same key1, and the same key2, and the same key3, they are all in the same "transaction group". Then I must give it some integer id in a new key named 'transaction_group_id'
- Else, consecutive documents that do not matck key1, key2 and key3 are all in their own individual "transaction_groups".

It's really easy to understand it by looking at the screenshot of a data sample (better than my explanation anyway). See here:

[image]

As you can see in the sample:
- Documents 1 and 2 are in the same group, because they match key1, key2 and key3;
- Documents 3 and 4 also match and are in their own group;
- Following the same logic, documents 18 and 19 are a group obviously. However, even though they match the values of documents 1 and 3, they are not in the same group (because the documents are not consecutive).

I created a very simplified version of the current python function, to give you guys an idea of the current implementation:

```
def groupTransactions(mongo_host,
                      mongo_port,
                      mongo_db,
                      mongo_collection):

"""
Group transactions if Keys 1, 2 and 3 all match in consecutive docs.
"""

    mc = MongoClient(mongo_host, mongo_port)
    db = mc['testdb']
    coll = db['test_collection']

    # The first document transaction group must always be equal to 1.
    first_doc_id = coll.find_one()['_id']
    coll.update({'_id': first_doc_id},
                {"$set": {"transaction_group_id": 1}},
                upsert=False, multi=False)

    # Cursor order is undetermined unless we use sort(), no matter what the _id is. We learned it the hard way.
    cur = coll.find().sort('subtransaction_id', ASCENDING)
    doc_count = cur.count()

    unique_data = []
    unique_data.append(cur[0]['key1'], cur[0]['key2'], cur[0]['key3'])
    transaction_group_id = 1
    i = 1

    while i < doc_count:

        doc_id = cur[i]['_id']
        unique_data.append(cur[i]['key1'], cur[i]['key2'], cur[i]['key3'])

        if unique_data[i] != unique_data[i-1]:
            # New group find, increase group id by 1
            transaction_group_id = transaction_group_id + 1

        # Update the group id in the database
        coll.update({'_id': doc_id},
                    {"$set": {"transaction_group_id": transaction_group_id}},
                    upsert=False, multi=False)

        i = i + 1

    print "%d subtransactions were grouped into %d transaction groups." % (doc_count, i)
    return 1
```

This is the code, more or less, and it works. But it takes between 2 to 3 days to finish, which is starting to become unacceptable. The hardware is good: VMs in last generation Xeon, local MongoDB in SSD, 128GB RAM). It will probably run fast if we decide to run it on AWS, use threading/subprocesses, etc - which are all obviously good options to try at some point.

However, I'm not convinced this is the best algorithm. It's just the best I could come up with.There must be obvious ways to improve it that I'm not seeing.

Moving to c/c++ or out of NoSQL is out of the question at this point. I have to make it work the way it is.

So basically the question is: Is this the best possible algorithm (using MongoDB/pymongo) in terms of speed? If not, I'd appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:** Just so you can have an idea of how slow this code performance is: Last time I measured it, it took **22 hours** to run on 1.000.000 results. As a quick workaround, I wrote something else to load the data to a Pandas DataFrame first and then apply the same logic of this code more or less. It took **3 to 4 minutes** to group everything, using the same hardware. I mean, I know Pandas is efficient, etc. But there's something wrong, there can't be such a huge gap between between the two solutions performances (4min vs 1,320min).

Comment: you are sorting by subtransaction_id - why? is there an index on it?  what is 'document'? what is _id? why not sort by that?  When the documents are saved in mongodb originally, is there a transaction_group_id field (set to 0 or -1 or whatever)?  Also what version are you on, and is this done only once per collection? (and new stuff goes into a new collection next month?)

Comment: subtransaction id is a guaranteed unique auto-incrementing integer id. Moreover, as I have to group consecutive transactions, I have to make sure the subtransactions are consecutive. Document is the term used in MongoDB to mean sort of what a row is in SQL. No there's no transaction_group_id of any kind previously set, it is the goal of this effort. How is version relevant? Yes, this is ran once every time new data comes in every month. Thanks.

Comment: your table has a column labeled "document" - that is what I was asking about.  What do the numbers in that column represent.  Also do transaction_group_ids have to be monotonically increasing or do they just have to be unique and actual value is not important?

Comment: NUmbers in the document key are unique autoincrement identifiers of subtransactions. The difference between this and the numbers in subtransaction_id is that subtransaction_id starts at 1 in each new DB. Document continues where it stopped in new dbs. Anyway, it is useless for this problem. Answering your other question, value is important, they should increase +1 at each new group.

Comment: are there any indexes on the collection?  What are you using for _id?  Since it's not clear how the data is getting into this coll to begin with. Also, it's important to me that you understand I'm not asking for details frivolously - if transaction_group_id field doesn't exist (say with val -1) then adding it will increase the size of the document, which means document will have to be physically moved. 2.6 would not have this as a problem because of different data allocation mechanism used by default.  And indexes question is because sorting on an unindexed column would be extremely slow.

Comment: btw, when you say it took 3-4 minutes to group in Panda - the grouping is fast, but majority of the time you are spending in this code is writing to the database, one update at a time, so unless you updated the data I think it's not at all comparable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help so far. Addressing your questions: I have just learned that the _id field is filled with ObjectID autogenerated by mongodb. The transaction_group_id key already exists for all documents in the db and it is set to "" (empty). We're just updating it with an integer, not creating it at every iteration. MongoDB version is 2.4.10. There column subtransaction_id is indexed. I have done some testing with different code and you are absolutely right about most of the time being spent with writing to the db. Maybe my focus should be: How to improve write speed to MongoDB.

Comment: ok, great, I can enumerate those ways in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case that most of the time is spent writing to the database, which includes the round trip of sending work to the DB, plus the DB doing the work.   I will point out a couple of places where you can speed up each of those.

### Speeding up the back-and-forth of sending write requests to the DB:

One of the best ways to improve the latency of the requests to the DB is to minimize the number of round trips.  In your case, it's actually possible because multiple documents will get updated with the same transaction_group_id.   If you accumulate their values and only send a "multi" update for all of them, then it will cut down on the back-and-forth.  The larger the transaction groups the more this will help.

In your code, you would replace the current update statement:

```
coll.update( {'_id': doc_id},
                {"$set": {"transaction_group_id": transaction_group_id}},
                upsert=False, multi=False)
```

With an accumulator of `doc_id` values (appending them to a list should be just fine).  When you detect the "pattern" change and transaction group go to the next one, you would then run one update for the whole group as:

```
coll.update( {'_id': {$in: list-of-docids },
                {"$set": {"transaction_group_id": transaction_group_id}},
                upsert=False, multi=True)
```

A second way of increasing parallelism of this process and speeding up end-to-end work would be to split the job between more than one client - the downside of this is that you need a single unit of work to pre-calculate how many transaction_group_id values there will be and where the split points are.   Then you can have multiple clients like this one which only handle range of specific `subtransaction_id` values and their transaction_group_id starting value is not 1 but whatever is given to them by the "pre-work" process.

### Speeding up the actual write on the DB:

The reason I asked about existence of the `transaction_group_id` field is because if a field that's being $set does not exist, it will be created and that increases the document size.  If there is not enough space for the increased document, it has to be relocated and that's less efficient than the in-place update.

MongoDB stores documents in BSON format.  Different BSON values have different sizes.  As a quick demonstration, here's a shell session that shows total document size based on the type  and size of value stored:

```
> db.sizedemo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abe7a5168d6c4735121c9"), "transaction_id" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abe7d5168d6c4735121ca"), "transaction_id" : -1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abe815168d6c4735121cb"), "transaction_id" : 9999 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abe935168d6c4735121cc"), "transaction_id" : NumberLong(123456789) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abed35168d6c4735121cd"), "transaction_id" : "   " }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("535abedb5168d6c4735121ce"), "transaction_id" : "          " }
> db.sizedemo.find().forEach(function(doc) { print(Object.bsonsize(doc)); })
43
46
46
46
46
53
```

Note how the empty string takes up three bytes fewer than double or NumberLong do.  The string "   " takes the same amount as a number and longer strings take proportionally longer.  To guarantee that your updates that `$set` the transaction group never cause the document to grow, you want to set transaction_group_id to the same size value on initial load as it will be updated to (or larger).  This is why I suggested -1 or some other agreed upon "invalid" or "unset" value.

You can check if the updates have been causing document moves by looking at the value in `db.serverStatus().metrics.record.moves` - this is the number of document moves caused by growth since the last time server was restarted.   You can compare this number before and after your process runs (or during) and see how much it goes up relative to the number of documents you are updating.